# Can't find cause of Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, openssl, valgrind

I am writing HTTP client in C++. When I was testing my program he crashed with this error:

```
*** Error in `./isabot': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffe7f8d2600 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x81299)[0x7fef1fd86299]
./isabot[0x408eca]
./isabot[0x409afe]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fef1fd27555]
./isabot[0x402d59]
======= Memory map: ========
.
.
.
```

I reran my program with valgrind -v and I got this error:

```
==20879== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==20879==    at 0x4C2B18A: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:576)
==20879==    by 0x408EC9: sendRequest(ssl_st*, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /homes/eva/xm/xmimoc01/ISA/isabot)
==20879==    by 0x409AFD: main (in /homes/eva/xm/xmimoc01/ISA/isabot)
==20879==  Address 0x1ffeffee00 is on thread 1's stack
==20879==  in frame #1, created by sendRequest(ssl_st*, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (???:)
==20879==
```

When I started my program without valgrind, the program crashed on this. But, when I started my program with valgrind, it wrote to me an error and the program continued successfully without repetition this error.

My function sendRequest() looks like:

```c
string sendRequest(SSL *ssl, int requestType, const string &botToken, const string &guildId, const string &channelId, const string &lastMessageId, const string &content)
{
    const char *request;
    string strRequest;
    stringstream response;
    string isChunked;
    char buffer[BUFFER];

    if (requestType == GET_CLIENT_ID) {
        strRequest = createIDRequest(botToken);
    }
    else if (requestType == GET_GUILDS) {
        strRequest = createGuildsRequest(botToken);
    }
    else if (requestType == GET_CHANNELS) {
        strRequest = createChannelRequest(botToken, guildId);
    }
    else if (requestType == GET_MESSAGES) {
        strRequest = createMessagesRequest(botToken, channelId);
    }
    else if (requestType == GET_ACTUAL_MESSAGES) {
        strRequest = createActualMessagesRequest(botToken, channelId, lastMessageId);
    }
    else if(requestType == POST_SEND_MESSAGE) {
        strRequest = createSendMessageRequest(botToken, channelId, content);
    }

    request = strRequest.c_str();

    SSL_write(ssl, request, strlen(request));

    while(true) {
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        int n =  SSL_read(ssl, buffer, BUFFER);

        if(n >= 0) {
            buffer[n] = '\0';
        }

        if (n <= 5) {
            break;
        };

        response << buffer;

        if (isResponseChunked(response.str()) != true) {
            break;
        }
    }
    

    return response.str();
}
```

and I called it from main.cpp in part of code where it crashed like this:

```c
string sendedMessage = sendRequest(conn.ssl, POST_SEND_MESSAGE, botToken, "", channelId, "", content);
```

Comment: This is crying out for a `switch` statement.

Comment: Is this a double `free` call? If so, you'll need to show us the code in which it occurs.

Comment: This question is not complete.  First, what is the `string` type being returned from `sendRequest()`?  Is it `std::string`?  And what value are you calling `delete` on?  Where is the code that calls `delete`?

Comment: There isn't any code which calls delete. Only background logic can..

Answer (score 1):

`buffer[n] = '\0';` will write past the end of `buffer` when `n == BUFFER`. This overwrites some part of the stack, likely snother local variable. If it is one of the `string` variables, the internal state is corrupted which could result in this error.

The simple fix is to allocate one additional character in `buffer`.

```cpp
char buffer[BUFFER+1];
```

Alternatively, you could read one less byte in the call to `SSL_read`.

Comment: An alternative fix, would be to not treat the buffer as zero terminated, and rather handle a separate length variable. Zero termination doesn't  work with binary data.

Comment: Yes, It could be the problem. I'll try! :)